# Cannot run Android Virtual Devices on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

On Android Studio, when I try to launch an AVD in the emulator, I get an error message of this form:

```
/Users/thomasreddington/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5_API_22
dyld: Symbol not found: _AVMediaTypeVideo
  Referenced from: /Users/thomasreddington/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator64-x86
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/thomasreddington/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator64-x86
```

I’ve tried making new AVDs with different features, but nothing seems to work. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I created an issue for this against the Tools project for AOSP.  Please feel free to add additional information there, https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=176338

Answer (score -1):

The AVD is garbage for Android. Your best bet is to use [GenyMotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/).